# Which precision is used by xarray weighted().mean()?

Tags: python, precision, python-xarray, weighted-average

I would like to understand when weighted().mean() is using simple or double precision.
There is a short example of the issue I have:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
data = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature")
weights = np.cos( np.deg2rad(data.lat) )   # weights with the cosinus of the latitude

# data are 32 bytes
data.air.dtype   # --> dtype('float32')
weights.dtype    # --> dtype('float32')

# mean() uses 32b
data.air.isel(time=1).mean().dtype   # --> dtype('float32')

# weighted().mean() uses 64b in some cases...
data.air.isel(time=1).weighted(weights).mean().dtype            # --> dtype('float64')
data.air.isel(time=slice(1,2)).weighted(weights).mean().dtype   # --> dtype('float64')

# ... but weighted().mean() keep using 32b if mean is not applied to all dimensions, why?
data.air.isel(time=slice(1,2)).weighted(weights).mean(("lon", "lat")).dtype   # --> dtype('float32')
```

Why weighted().mean() is using 32 bytes instead of 64 if mean() is not applied to all dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

edit: I just updated my environments and this no longer happened. I am not sure which library is responsible (not numpy it seems)

---

This is due to a somewhat inconsistent behavior of `where` in xarray. Compare

```
dta = data.air.isel(time=slice(1,2))

# only one element
dta.where([True]).dtype # -> float64
# many elements
dta.where(dta.lat > 0) # -> float32
```

I am not sure *why* `where` behaves different in the two situations. So I think you get `float64` when you reducing over *all* dimensions.

This happens within [`_sum_of_weights`](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/19c2626f4beb1678180489275b152f9bb1673721/xarray/core/weighted.py#L151).

```
sum_of_weights = xr.dot(dta.notnull(), weights)
valid_weights = sum_of_weights != 0.0
print(sum_of_weights.where(valid_weights).dtype) # -> float32


sum_of_weights = xr.dot(dta.notnull(), weights, dims=...)
valid_weights = sum_of_weights != 0.0
print(sum_of_weights.where(valid_weights).dtype) # -> float64
```